# Problem getting XML node attribute value with nokogiri

Tags: xml, itunes, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an XML file from iTunes using nokogiri and rails 3.

Here is my code:

```
itunes_top_300 = Nokogiri.HTML(open("http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=300/xml"))

itunes_top_300.search('//entry').each do |podcast|
  url = podcast.xpath("//[@href]]").text
  return podcast.url
end
```

When I load up the view that calls this method, I get:

undefined method `url'

Here is the xml I'm trying to parse:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=300/xml

Thanks in advance,

Harris

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  I needed to search the document using ('//feed/entry') rather than just ('//entry').

Comment: your question made me find a fault with my installation of nokogiri, tanks .:-)

Comment: That cannot possibly have been your problem.

Comment: `//feed/entry` means _"Find every `<entry>` element in the document that is a child of a `<feed>` element at any level"_, while `//entry` means _"Find every `<entry>` element in the document at any level."_ As the former is a subset of the latter, this would only make a difference if you were getting too many `entry` elements. However, in the URL you have supplied, every `entry` element is a child of the `feed`. Making that change to the xpath does not affect the end result one bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you have stated that your code is working again, let me point out some flaws in your code:

1. You are asking Nokogiri to parse the XML RSS feed as HTML. You should instead use `Nokogiri::XML( ... )`; not a big deal, and not the cause of this problem.
2. You are using a `return` inside your each. In the code you have shown, that would normally cause a `LocalJumpError: unexpected return`. Clearly you are using this code inside a method (that you have not shown us). Using `return` inside a block does not exit the block, but rather causes the enclosing method to return. As for what you probably want instead, read on:
3. You are creating a local `url` variable, but you are not using it.
4. I am guessing that what you were trying to do is find just the `url` from each feed. However, by using the XPath `//[@href]` what you were really doing is finding every element in the document that has an `href="..."` attribute. You are re-finding this full set of elements for each `entry` in the document. (Except, due to the `return` statement, you were exiting early.) And then, by asking for the `text` of the element, you would have been getting nothing.
5. As for the actual error you were getting, you were attempting to access `podcast.url`, but Nokogiri elements do not have a `url` method.

Given the schema of the feeds from the URL you have supplied, here are different ways to get an array of the `href="..."` attribute of every `entry/link` in the document, in increasing order of simplicity and preference:

**Near-Direct Translation**

```
urls = []
itunes_top_300.search('//entry').each do |podcast|
  # Find the first element below the current one that has an href attribute
  # and then get the value of that attribute
  url = podcast.at_xpath(".//[@href]")['href']

  # Add this url to the array
  urls << url
end

# As the last statement in your method, return urls (without word 'return')
urls
```

**Getting rid of the local variable**

```
urls = []
itunes_top_300.search('//entry').each do |podcast|
  # It's pretty clear what we're doing, so no need to name the value
  # before we add it to the array
  urls << podcast.at_xpath(".//[@href]")['href']
end
urls
```

**Cleaning it up with Map**

```
# Run through the array and convert each element to the return value
# of the block
itunes_top_300.search('//entry').map do |podcast|
  podcast.at_xpath(".//[@href]")['href']
end

# If the above is the last statement of the method, the method will return the
# result of the map as the return value of the method
```

**Asking for just the attribute directly**

```
itunes_top_300.search('//entry').map do |podcast|
  # Instead of getting the element, get the attribute itself
  # Use `to_s` or `value` to get the text of the attribute node.
  podcast.at_xpath(".//[@href]/@href").to_s
end
```

**Using only XPath to get what we wanted in the first place**

```
# Take an array of attribute nodes and get their values
itunes_top_300.xpath('//entry/link/@href').map{ |attr| attr.to_s }
```

**Using Ruby 1.9 syntax to shorten the map call**

```
# Map the result of the XPath by calling `to_s` on each
itunes_top_300.xpath('//entry/link/@href').map( &:to_s )
```